# Vpython text as current time

Tags: python, vpython

I'm a beginner with vpython, trying to make something like clock using text. The problem is that text actually changes but the older one stays, I have tried setting up visibility to flase, but it starts blinking. Is there proper way to do it?

```
from vpython import *
import time
while True:
    rate(1000)
    hour=time.localtime(time.time())[3]
    minute=time.localtime(time.time())[4]
    second=time.localtime(time.time())[5]
    textHour = str(hour)
    textHour = textHour.zfill(2)
    textMinute = str(minute)
    textMinute = textMinute.zfill(2)
    textSecond = str(second)
    textSecond = textSecond.zfill(2)
    current_time = textHour + ":" + textMinute + ":" + textSecond
    myLabel = text(text=current_time, align='center', color=color.orange, pos=vector(0,0,0))
    # myLabel.visible=False
```

Comment: You need to create your text label ONCE, and then update it with new text.  I don't know the `vpython` API, but there must be a way to change the attributes of a widget after it is created.

Comment: Create `mylabel` outside of the loop, then do `mylabel.text = current_time`.

Comment: After I added: myLabel = text(text="sample text", align='center', color=color.orange, pos=vector(0, 0, 0)) before the loop and instead of creating new object I changed value of text in the last line of the loop, it doesn't change, it's "sample text" all the time

Comment: Sorry, that was bad advice.  I see now on in the docs that won't work, because `text` is so expensive.  They suggest using the `label` widget instead of the `text` widget.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Not really, I'll try to check out some tutorials and hopefully it  will work

Comment: It actually works, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Here is the label documentation:

https://www.glowscript.org/docs/VPythonDocs/label.html